# Wireless Network Interface name changes sometime after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, systemctl

On my arch linux machine,for some reason the interface name of my wirless network device sometimes changes from "wlp2s0" to "wlan0". I then have to setup my network manually or restart the computer.

I can't see a pattern when this happens. All I know is that it sometimes happens after rebooting.

- How can I detect the device name in a systemctl service?
- How can I set the device name in a systemctl service?
- How can I figure out why this happpens? Which logfiles should I read?

If you need some more information of my system, please ask in the comment section.

Comment: I think you should ask people in the Arch IRC ( #archlinux on irc.freenode.org ) because the feedback loop is much quicker and your question doesn't really fit the question answer style of superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- about how you can detect the device name: you can run either `ls /sys/class/net` or `ip link`

  - udev is responsible for which device gets which name. Systemd v197 introduced Predictable Network Interface Names, which automatically assigns static names to network devices. Interfaces are now prefixed with `en` (ethernet), `wl` (WLAN), or `ww` (WWAN) followed by an automatically generated identifier, creating an entry such as `enp0s25`.

This behavior may be disabled by adding `net.ifnames=0` in your kernel command line. (source:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Configuration)

Hope this helps.